# Rails validation on form, not record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I have a Rails input form on which one field is not directly related to a field in the underlying object: I have to do some calculation before putting it into the ActiveRecord field. That's ok so far: I just put the calculation into the controller.

My problem is that the calculation can fail, and I want to report that to the user. I know how to do that with a flash alert, but that doesn't associate the error with the specific form entry field and is inconsistent with the errors that record validation gives. What I want to do is tell the form which entry field has failed, and why.

All the documentation I can find on that uses ActiveRecord validations, but that's too late: I can't create the ActiveRecord because I don't have the data to populate it (and even if I populate it with invalid dummy data -- yech! -- I've lost the details of what caused the error by the time it hits the validation).

So what's the Rails way of generating form validation errors from a controller (ok, ok, but I want to get it working before I refactor it into a concern) rather from a model validator? Or what should I be doing instead?

Edit:
Here's an example of the sort of think I'm trying to do. Imagine a fleet manager dealing with thousands of vehicles, identified by their registration numbers (licence plates). When a vehicle is checked out to a driver, there's no point offering a drop-down with thousands of items, so the user enters the registration number. The controller looks this up (or, better, passes it to the model to look up), it gets matched to the vehicle record, and vehicle record id gets put into the checkout. If the user mistypes the number, the controller/model (probably) finds there's no entry for that vehicle. I know want to tell the user why the save has failed, in a way that's consistent with other validation failures.

Comment: You can use a virtual attribute. Add it in the form and place your validation on it

Comment: @Mandeep has the right idea. This logic should not really be in a controller but rather in the model itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My problem is that the calculation can fail, and I want to report that to the user.

**Virtual Attributes:**

***Virtual attributes are a clean way to add form fields that do not map directly to the database*** and i think it fit nicely with your needs. To create a *virtual attribute you can add this line in your Model:*

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor  :your_field
end
```

***After that you can add this field in form and prefill it after doing calculation by js. You can then add a custom validation in your model and check if the calculation is right or not***.

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor  :your_field

  validate :some_custom_validation_method

  def some_custom_validation_method
    # some logic 
  end
end
```

For more details you can checkout this [`railscast episode on virtual attributes`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes-revised)

Comment: I had wondered about doing it that way. Can I do the calculation in the model rather than in js, as in the (older) RailsCast? Largely because I know js even less than I know Ruby/Rails, but also because all the stuff I need is readily accessible in the model. 

I'd need to make the whole thing atomic, though: the calculation involves look-up in other records, so unless I make it atomic there's a risk that the calculation I used to validate the form could be wrong by the time I come to update the record. Or can I raise the validation error from directly within the setter?

Comment: @digitig i asked you to do calculation in js because you need to populate it based on users selection in form and that way  if the calculation fails user will also know what actually is happening otherwise imagine you don't show calculated field to user and then all of a sudden user starts to get that validation error and he/she will ponder what just happened

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm still not sure where the js would come in. I've expanded the question to give an example of the sort of thing I'm trying to do.

Comment: @digitig Ah i see. In your case you don't need anything. You have two options a) You can do it by Ajax, when user enters registration details you can fire a request to some custom method which will check for it's validity and then give proper response to user. b) You can make your form a two step form, first when user enters registration details and submit this form then you check for it's validity and renders second part of your from which will have other details. Personally i would favour the Ajax approach but then it depends on what you want in your app

Comment: Ok, I'll take that as the answer, and I'll go and learn Ajax. I had a feeling I'd end up with Ajax, but I was trying to follow the "Agile Web Development with Rails 4" approach of getting it working before Ajax-ifying it.